# Laravel - Check for new message inside conversation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I created application in Laravel where users can communicate using Facebook-like messages. Now I have problem when I check for new messages. I created function which needs to query all conversations and all messages inside those conversations to find new (unopened) messages.

So I'm asking if there is different way for achiving this - without stressing too much the server with all those queries.

This is my function:

```
function newMessage(){
    if(Auth::check()){
        $conversations = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->conversations;
        $new = false;
        foreach ($conversations as $key => $value) {
            if(count(Conversation::find($value->id)->messages()->where("user_id", "!=", Auth::user()->id)->where("opened", "=", 0)->get()) > 0){
                $new = true;
            }
        }

        return $new;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Relationship between `conversation` and `message` is one to many.
Conversation table consists only of `id` and message table has `id` and `opened` (I'm giving you only relevant columns).

Comment: Why is the relationship between conversation and message many-to-many? Shouldn't it be one-to-many ?

Comment: You can keep a column in conversations table containing the number of new (or unread messages).

Any time this column is > 0 for a conversation, means that there are new messages. If some new messages are read, then just reset this counter for that conversation to zero.

Comment: @faust Actually it is one to many, I made mistake while typing the question

Comment: @AfzalivE multiple users are in same conversation, so if I create column in conversation table for new messages, then the counter would be reseted for all users in that conversation

Comment: I think the only way to do it is to make another table "id, user_id, message_id, is_opened" and then check if the current user has read the message... this kinda breaks the whole relationship model, but I can't think of anything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

- created `opened` column in `conversation_user` table
- when user opens a message `opened` column updates to 1
- when user sends message, `opened` column updates to 0 for every user in that conversation except for the user who sends the message

And I wrote this function which will check if user has new messages (inside `User` model):

```
public function hasUnread(){
    return (bool)$this->conversations()->whereOpened(0)->count();
}
```